# Enable Html5smartimage xtype in Multifield AEM

Tags: aem

I'm trying to create a multifield that has textfield and image field. However when I add HTML5Smartimage xtype to multifield, I can't drag and drop images to it. 
The html5smratimage xtype has all the required properties set. Images show the multifield config and dialog. Am I Missing any properties? Can anyone help me? Thank in advance

Comment: What properties have you set?

Comment: @joepd i have set the following props -
Xtype - html5smartimage, fileReferenceParameter - ./someValue, fileNameReference - ./somevalue, name - ./somevalue, height - 250, ddGroups-media, allowBlank - false and allowUpload - false